# How to properly use Google Cloud IoT Core over HTTPS regarding to SSL certificates?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-iot

I use Cloud IoT mqtt bridge via HTTPS as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/http-bridge#setting_device_state). I created public/private keys pair to sign JWT token. Everything is ok except one thing.

As you can see the origin for the service is https://cloudiotdevice.googleapis.com. And this domain resolves to different addresses. The client fails to verify some of these hosts certificates. So some requests fail.

It's also easy to use any browser to see the issue (certificate verification failure). Just open the above link server will respond with `404`, but browser anyway shows whether the certificate is ok or isn't.

I collected bunch (seven) of IP addresses and downloaded certificates.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/support/troubleshooting) is told that if there are TLS issues it's may be necessary to install root CA certs. [The repo of certs is here](https://pki.goog/repository/). I downloaded first three of these CA certs and tried different ways to install these to the system (`update-ca-certificates` for ubuntu, `trust anchor` for arch). I tried to install them to the browser (Chrome) as Authority Certs and see whether it stops complaining. I tried to verify the server certificates via openssl e.g.

```
openssl verify -untrusted ca-bundle cert.pem
```

But I couldn't get it verified. What have I missed?

Comment: Would the 404 error be because we are performing a GET request at "/" and there is no service at that endpoint?  From the doc, wouldn't the method need to be a POST and the path be /v1/projects/{project-id}/locations/{cloud-region}/registries/{registry-id}/devices/{deviceid}:setState

Comment: Yes it's `POST` request sent to `https://cloudiotdevice.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project-id}/locations/{cloud-region}/registries/{registry-id}/devices/{deviceid}:setState`, but `GET` request to `/` from browser is just for inspecting the certificate.

Comment: I’ve noticed that you mention using the MQTT bridge and you follow the troubleshooting for MQTT connections but you link to following the HTTP bridge/HTTP connections guidelines.
I understand then, you are using the HTTP bridge. You should ensure a couple things. First, that the JWT token is refreshed before every call (to ensure it does not become outdated). Second, given that only some requests fail I would suggest implementing an [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff) retry and check if the failed connections work upon retrial.

Comment: Let me know if the previous comment helps or not. Sharing the exact error you are obtaining would also help troubleshooting.

Comment: The error is `ECONNRESET` while TLS handshake. I investigated into this, but eventually decided to refuse Google IoT and use own hosted mosquitto due to design. And what I realized it looks like the issue relates to DNS cache (`systemd-resolved`). The Google MQTT IoT service has dynamic infrastructure when host spots are up and down often as I think for savings reasons. So IP addresses are reassigned to different hosts often.

Comment: In `https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/protocols` you can find the differences in between the HTTP bridge and the MQTT bridge, I believe you might find this documentation useful, given that you have been citing both of them interchangeably. When you create a device registry, you can select which protocol to use (or both of them).  Nonetheless, if you were to try again with Cloud IoT, please try to implement exponential backoff and if the issue is still happening, consider contacting Google Cloud Platform Support as a more detailed overview of your configuration might be needed.

Comment: Thanx, I saw this link.